# How to exclude CSS files from compilation in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have some css files which I would like to exclude from my project's compilation (I would like their compilation errors to not result in my project being underlined in red).

I have tried adding their directory to preferences->compilation->excludes, but it seems they are still being complied -- their errors still show on the problems view and they still result in red underlines in my project view. Any suggestions of other steps I should try?

Comment: Have you tried to mark directory as "Excluded" in project tree?

Comment: @y.bedrov is that in the context menu when I right click on a folder in the project pane? I don't see that option...

Comment: Yes, there should be "Mark  Directory As" option.